# What exactly do I upload to Github?

Tags: github

I'm using Github for the first time, and I'm confused on what I'm supposed to upload. I already created a repository, but which files am I supposed to upload? Do I only upload the source code, or do I add files like the YAML and gradle files?

Comment: Add everything you would want to keep in source control, including all source files and configuration files but not including things like assets and sensitive secrets.

Comment: Ah yeah, @Abion47 makes a good point about sensitive data. 

Comment: @Fogmeister Source control is not a backup. It's for maintaining a history of changes that you can monitor and, if necessary, reverse. It works as a backup of sorts for things like source code, but you should not be using it to back up your entire project.

Comment: @Abion47 true. But in a small comment there’s only so much to say. You said it much better than I did. 